# Parse.com cloud code query 2 class results

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In my project, I've 2 classes - gamePlayer and User. In gamePlayer, I've created pointer called playerId to hold the pointer value to the User class.
When I query both classes seperately in cloud code, it works correctly.
Now, i'm trying to query the gamePlayer class with the constraint

```
query.notEqualTo("playerId", request.params.id);
```

it gives the players which will be opponents for the current user.
How can I get the result of both the queries in a single cloud code function?

Comment: Your question not clear enough, please explain yourself better and add more code.

Comment: Are you trying to query two different classes using single query?
Or you want using the data of the first query in the second query?

Comment: I want to get the opponents (playerId) selected from 'User' class in a random way, but the condition is that the current user should not have played with the previous 5 users, means the program should not select the random opponent user again and again the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `request.user` in cloud code to get the calling user.

Since playerId is a pointer to users, all you need to do is:

`query.notEqualTo("playerId", request.user);`